# grails findWhere not equal

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to use [`findWhere`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findWhere.html) and a not equal value (trying to use it vs criterias)?

E.g.

```
Books.findWhere('sale' : true, 'category': ne('exclude me') )
```

I have a working solution, but was wondering if there was a way to use `findWhere` I find it simpler to read.

```
def result = Books.createCriteria().get{
            eq('sale', true)
            ne("category", 'exclude me')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the dynamic finder methods:

```
Books.findAllBySaleAndCategoryNotEqual(true, 'exclude me')
```

or the where queries (which use `DetachedCriteria`:

```
Books.findAll {
     (sale == true) && (category != 'exclude me')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to do it with `findWhere` but there is a nice syntax for two-property dynamic finders where one is a `boolean`

```
Books.findSaleByCategoryNotEqual('exclude me')
```

(or `findNotSaleBy...` if you want sale to be `false`).